# Imprimir contenido de stack LIFO de tipo personalizado

Tags: c++

Tengo la siguiente clase;

```
class Estudiante {

private:
    string nombre,cedula;
    int matricula;
    float calificacion;

public:
    //se dejo con un destructor por defecto
    void anadir(int _matricula,string _nombre,string _cedula,float _calificacion);
    void insertar();
    void borrar();
    void listar();
    void listar_inverso();
    void promedio();
    int getMatricula() const {
        return matricula;
    }
    float getCalificacion() const {
        return calificacion;
    }

};
/**
* Este metodo es utilizado para asignarle los datos a cada una de las propiedades
* de esta manera el objeto con todas sus propiedades asignadas se almacenan
* en el vector de estudiantes
**/
void Estudiante::anadir(int _matricula,string _nombre,string _cedula,float _calificacion) {
    matricula = _matricula;
    nombre = _nombre;
    cedula = _cedula;
    calificacion = _calificacion;
}
/**
* Lista los estudiantes, es utilizado por el vecto junto a un
* iterador
**/
void Estudiante::listar() {
    cout << matricula <<" "  << nombre <<" " << cedula <<" " << calificacion << endl;

}
```

La misma la utilizo para crear objetos del tipo `estudiante` y guardarlos en una pila del tipo de la clase;

```
stack<Estudiante> lista_estudiantes;

Estudiante *est;
//Nuevo objeto de tipo estudiante
est = new Estudiante;

est->anadir(100,"estudent1","000-000000-0",88);
lista_estudiantes.push(*est);
est->anadir(200,"estudent2","000-000000-0",80);
lista_estudiantes.push(*est);
est->anadir(300,"estudent3","000-000000-0",95);
lista_estudiantes.push(*est);
```

He intentado lo siguiente;

```
for ( int it = 0; it < lista_estudiantes.size(); ++it ){
                    est->listar();
                }
```

Pero en este caso solo obtengo el ultimo elemento creado, no todos, si tengo 3 elementos creados me imprime 3 veces el ultimo;

```
MATRICULA |   NOMBRE  |    CEDULA    | CALIFICACION |
300         estudent3   000-000000-0        95
300         estudent3   000-000000-0        95
300         estudent3   000-000000-0        95
```

Todo esto al compilar funciona, corre y puedo registrar `estudiantes`, ahora bien no logro imprimir el contenido de mi pila.

Comment: Podrias explicar que quiere decir que no das con la solucion? que le pasa al metodo listar?

Comment: @gbianchi he modificado la pregunta para agregar el contenido que me faltaba y la info adicional con lo que obtengo al intentar imprimir.

Comment: Tu programa hace lo que pedis. En teoria si es una pila, no deberias poder recorrerla. Si queres violar ese principio, tu metodo listar deberia recibir que posicion qieres mostrar

Comment: @gbianchi si estoy erróneo me gustaría corregir, eso me ayudaría.

Comment: Stack de que tipo es? porque la que tenes que listar es esa, no a la clase estudiante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pero en este caso solo obtengo el ultimo elemento creado, no todos, si tengo 3 elementos creados me imprime 3 veces el ultimo;

Visto tu código es el resultado esperado, no tienes que sorprenderte por ello. Fíjate que en el bucle solo va a cambiar `it`... el puntero `est` es el mismo todo el rato:

```
for ( int it = 0; it < lista_estudiantes.size(); ++it ){
  est->listar();
}
```

Por otro lado, en una pila no es posible iterar por sus elementos (por eso es una pila y no un vector). Para recuperar sus elementos puedes optar por cambiar `stack` por `vector` o a vaciar la pila (metiendo sus elementos en otro contenedor)... no existen mecanismos para iterar pilas.

Salvo que el uso de la pila sea un requisito yo optaría por usar `std::vector` en vez de `std::stack`. Este contenedor tiene funciones que le permiten emular el comportamiento de una pila *LIFO*:

- `push_back`: Añade un elemento al final de la lista
- `pop_back`: Elimina el último elemento de la lista
- `back`: Obtiene una referencia al último elemento de la lista

Y además, al no ser una pila, es posible iterar sus elementos:

```
// Iteracion por indices
for ( int i= 0; i< lista_estudiantes.size(); ++i){
  lista_estudiantes[i].listar();
}

// Con iteradores
for( auto it = lista_estudiantes.begin(); it != lista_estudiantes.end(); ++it )
  it->listar();
}

// C++14
for( Estudiante estudiante : lista_estudiantes )
  estudiante.listar();
}
```

**Comentario recibido:**

> Es una tarea universitaria. Con vectores tengo el mismo programa y funciona obvio sabemos que un vector si posee todo lo necesario para esto, ahora el maestro quiere que sea con la pila por lo que me parece voy a tener que buscar una alternativa.

Si usas la pila es un requisito entonces tendrás que optar por vaciarla cada vez que quieras mostrar su contenido... y volver a rellenarla manteniendo el orden de los elementos. Y para realizar esta tarea necesitamos... otra pila!!!:

```
stack<Estudiante> temporal;

// Paso 1: listamos elementos
while( !lista_estudiantes.empty() )
{
  Estudiante estudiante = lista_estudiantes.top();
  lista_estudiantes.pop();
  estudiante.listar();

  temporal.push(estudiante);
}

// Paso 2: restauramos la pila
while( !temporal.empty() )
{
  Estudiante estudiante = temporal.top();
  temporal.pop();
  lista_estudiantes.push(estudiante);
}
```

Comment: Es una tarea universitaria. Con vectores tengo el mismo programa y funciona obvio sabemos que un vector si posee todo lo necesario para esto, ahora el maestro quiere que sea con la pila por lo que me parece voy a tener que buscar una alternativa.. Gracias por aclararme también.